# Adding words or URL endpoints from file to a another file consisting of URLS

Tags: python-3.x, url, url-rewriting, python-requests

So basically imagine I have a url list like:

```
https://google.com/
https://store.google.com/
https://gmail.google.com/
```

And I have another list of endpoints:

```
./endpoint
./path/endpoint
../../../path/endpoint
```

what I want is this:

```
https://google.com/endpoint
https://store.google.com/path/endpoint
https://gmail.google.com/path/endpoint
```

And then making a request.

The list I have are much bigger, in the thousands. But what I'm trying to accomplish is to take the endpoints list, and loop through it, appending them to the list of urls. Return status code, header, etc. Once it cycles through the whole list, move on to the next one. I can't code worth a darn but I'm learning.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, maybe drop some links that would give me ideas. I'm still trying to learn how to open a file(url list) for 'r+', return one line, open the other file(endpoints) as 'r+', append the words to the urls, etc, etc. Seems like I'm in way over my head at my novice skill level but this is something that I must accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have your URLs in a list `urls`, as

```
urls = ['https://google.com/','https://store.google.com/','https://gmail.google.com/']
```

Then you can have a list of endpoints:

```
endPoints = ['endpoint1','endpoint2','endPoint3']
```

Now, in order to create URLs, you can loop through both of these lists, and append URLs and endpoints, and save output generated accordingly:

```
mp = dict()
for url in urls:
    for endPoint in endPoints:
        totalUrl = url+endPoint
        mp[totalUrl] = request.get(totalUrl)
```

Now you can iterate over the dict, and use the request object accordingly

Comment: Both the url and endpoints are in two sperate files. There are a minimum of 1000 in each list. So yeah it is a list but it's not formatted the way you wrote it. Or will python interpret the list in the files this way. The file is a list ( url + \n all the to the end of file). Your reply definitely gives me an idea though. Because like i said in the question, I want to append all endoints to one url in the list, return data, then move on the next url in the list, until urls are used up. It's tough not knowing much python, ya know. I chose to learn as I go.

Comment: I've deleted two comments so far because when hit enter to go to newline it just saves edit. So I used the code you provided but the request failed so I decided to print the totalUrl. Main url on one line and the endpoints being put on a newline so obviously bad request. Looks like this.  https://api.postman.com
                                                                                ./suggestAlternatives.js